# Based on debit amount i want to make as red and for Credit i want to make as black using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

Based on debit amount i want to make as red and for Credit i want to make as black using jquery mobile..this is my code and I am getting only red color for both amount..please see my code and suggest me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert("working")
    //"Status=0&RefNo=000000000016&Amt=+22,434.64&ClearAmt=+22,434.64&Stmt=30-08-2011;TRF thru I;D;2787.00;INR;@29-08-2011;Sweep Trf ;C;25000.00;INR;@29-08-2011;MICR INWAR;D;250.00;INR;@29-08-2011;MICR INWAR;D;14250.00;INR;@29-08-2011;MICR INWAR;D;10250.00;INR;@29-08-2011;MICR INWAR;D;1000.00;INR;@27-08-2011;Sweep Trf ;C;1000.00;INR;@27-08-2011;TRF to NEF;D;1900.00;INR;@26-08-2011;0102820001;D;40000.00;INR;@26-08-2011;TRF to NEF;D;9999.00;INR;@&AccNo=SBA-01010600006521";
    //alert(_MiniStatement);
    var MiniStatementDATA = _MiniStatement.split("&")[4];
    var MiniStatementArray = MiniStatementDATA.split("@");
    Date1 = new Array();
    Amount = new Array();
    Details = new Array();
    //Currency = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < MiniStatementArray.length - 1; i++) {

        MiniStatementArray_temp = MiniStatementArray[i].split(";");
        alert(MiniStatementArray_temp);
        //MiniStatementArray_temp1 = MiniStatementArray_temp.split("")
        result = buildJson1(MiniStatementArray_temp);
        Date1[i] = result.date1;
        Amount[i] = result.Amount;
        alert(Amount);
        Details[i] = result.Details;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < MiniStatementArray.length - 1; i++) {

        $("#MiniSummaryId").append("<tr><td align='center'>" + Date1[i].replace("Stmt=", "") + "</td><td align='right' style=''> if (debit == D)  $("Amount_class").css("color", "FF0000")" +  Amount[i] + "</td><td align='left' style= " padding" >" + Details[i] + "</td>");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lot of things here:

- You should siphon off structural text as soon as possible. You've left the `Stmt=` text as part of the first date value, until the very last moment when you remove it from all date values, even those without it. The `Stmt=` text is not even associated with any date value, it's just structural text associated with the key-value pair that contains the statement data at the shallowest nesting level in the encoded data string, and your code sort of accidentally on purpose pulls it into the first date value by virtue of where it's positioned in the data. You should instead remove it as soon as you extract the statement data string.
- You should use double-quotes in HTML and single-quotes in JavaScript. That's a more common coding style, and helps to eliminate a lot of backslash-escaping, which, incidentally, you haven't even done in locations where it was needed.
- Please don't construct frickin huge concatenated strings on one line; start with an empty string and build it up one fragment at a time in a logical way. This makes for much more readable code.
- Try to precompute derived values where possible; this also enhances readability. See what I did with `cssColor` in the final loop.
- If you have control over the date format, please use `%Y-%m-%d`, and *never use any other format*. See http://xkcd.com/1179/.

Here's fixed code:

```js
var input = 'Status=0&RefNo=000000000016&Amt=+22,434.64&ClearAmt=+22,434.64&Stmt=30-08-2011;TRF thru I;D;2787.00;INR;@29-08-2011;Sweep Trf ;C;25000.00;INR;@29-08-2011;MICR INWAR;D;250.00;INR;@29-08-2011;MICR INWAR;D;14250.00;INR;@29-08-2011;MICR INWAR;D;10250.00;INR;@29-08-2011;MICR INWAR;D;1000.00;INR;@27-08-2011;Sweep Trf ;C;1000.00;INR;@27-08-2011;TRF to NEF;D;1900.00;INR;@26-08-2011;0102820001;D;40000.00;INR;@26-08-2011;TRF to NEF;D;9999.00;INR;@&AccNo=SBA-01010600006521';
var stmtData = input.split('&')[4].replace(/^Stmt=/,'');
var arrayData = stmtData.split('@');
var num = arrayData.length-1; // exclude final element, which is empty

var dates = [];
var details = [];
var creditDebits = [];
var amounts = [];
var currencies = [];
for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    var fieldData = arrayData[i].split(';');
    dates.push(fieldData[0]);
    details.push(fieldData[1]);
    creditDebits.push(fieldData[2]);
    amounts.push(fieldData[3]);
    currencies.push(fieldData[4]);
} // end for

for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    var cssColor = creditDebits[i] === 'C' ? 'black' : 'red';
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td align="center">'+dates[i]+'</td>';
    html += '<td align="right" style="color:'+cssColor+';">'+amounts[i]+'</td>';
    html += '<td align="left">'+details[i]+'</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $("#MiniSummaryId").append(html);
} // end for
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="MiniSummaryId" border="1">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong formatting in jquery !

```
        $("#MiniSummaryId").append("<tr><td align='center'>" + Date1[i].replace("Stmt=", "") + "</td><td align='right' style=''> if (debit == 'D')  $("Amount_class").css("color", "FF0000")" +  Amount[i] + "</td><td align='left' style= " padding" >" + Details[i] + "</td>");
```

Comment: if (debit == D)  , you need to use here as  if (debit == 'D')

Comment: thnk u but still its not working..anything other thn that i should makes changes ?